# One try catch with many retry points

Tags: c#

In a code like this

```
public static void Sub()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ile liczb chcesz odjąć?");
        RetryPoint1:
        try
        {
            int liczby = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] cyfry = new int[liczby];
            Console.WriteLine("Będziesz odejmować " + liczby + " liczb");
            for (int i = 0; i < liczby; i++)
            {   
                RetryPoint2:
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wpisz " + (i + 1) + " liczbę");
                    cyfry[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nie liczba!");
                    goto RetryPoint2;
                }  
            }                   
            int wynik = cyfry[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < liczby; i++)
            {
                wynik = wynik - cyfry[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Wynik to " + wynik);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nie liczba!");
            goto RetryPoint1;
        }
    }
```

there are two points where same exception(not int as user input) can occur. Is there some way to use retry point as variable that changes depending on when this error happened? Is it even a "valid" way of doing things in this case? Once can imagine that those try catches could start nesting quickly if there were more points within one function where the same exception could happen. I know I could put next try catch below for better readeability, but if there's same exception occurting every time, isn't there some more "right" way to handle it, with just one try catch?

Comment: Using of `goto` [is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

Comment: My personal opinion, I'd never use goto.

Comment: It appears that you're relying on exception handling to deal with invalid input.  Using `int.TryParse` will eliminate the need for exception handling and the `goto`s. Then you can use small loops for retrying on invalid input.

Comment: You're catching all exception types. Are you sure you would want to catch, for example, OutOfMemoryException and handle it this way? It might make more sense to use int.TryParse instead of using exceptions for control flow. And the gotos can be rewritten with while loops.

Comment: Say a Big NO to Goto..

Comment: Is it just me or you just changed the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `goto` at all for "RetryPoints" here. It's strongly advised to not use `goto` in scenarios like this.

Also don't use `Convert.ToInt32` to handle user input, use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead.

This is how your code could look like without using `goto` and using `int.TryParse` in favor of `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
public static void Sub()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ile liczb chcesz odjąć?");

    int liczby;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out liczby))
        Console.WriteLine("Nie liczba!");

    int[] cyfry = new int[liczby];

    Console.WriteLine("Będziesz odejmować " + liczby + " liczb");

    for (int i = 0; i < liczby; i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wpisz " + (i + 1) + " liczbę");

            if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out cyfry[i])) break;

            Console.WriteLine("Nie liczba!");
        }
    }

    int wynik = cyfry[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < liczby; i++)
        wynik -= cyfry[i];

    Console.WriteLine("Wynik to " + wynik);
}
```